# Unwanted text size change on scroll on dropdown menu

Tags: css

I have a dropdown menu on which links get bigger when the page is scrolled. This unfortunately then threatens to drop the bottom-most ones off the foot of the page as a result.

The site is http://www.jswhite.co.uk/

Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

here is the problem

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 981px)
.et-fixed-header #top-menu li a {
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

you used @media .. Try deleting this statement

you can also just paste this css code

```
.et-fixed-header #top-menu li a {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your javascript code adding class "et-fixed-header" at header tag and in your css you using below code.
 `@media only screen and (min-width: 981px)
.et-fixed-header #top-menu li a {
    font-size: 22px;
}`

So after adding et-fixed-header class it changing menu text. change your css.

```
.et-fixed-header #top-menu li a {
font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. set font size important to maintain it while scrolling

   #top-menu li li a {
     font-size: 16px!important;
     line-height: 1.1em;
    }
2. add overflow as scroll

   #main-header .nav li ul {
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
     overflow: scroll;
   }